# Bigquery convert String with mode repeated to Record type with mode repeated

Tags: google-cloud-platform, struct, google-bigquery

I have the following schema in bigquery with string type and mode repeated. I would like to convert the string to record type

The input schema looks like -
[image]

and the input data preview looks like this -

| query | user | keyword_db_tb | dataset | tablename |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| select a.*, b.* from dsip.accounts a join qwe.sales b | sys | 123 | dsip | accounts |
|  |  |  | qwe | sales |
| select * from forkp.facts where id in (select id from hjp.classes) | sys | 456 | forkp | facts |
|  |  |  | hjp | classes |

The output schema with the last 3 columns converted to record type should look like-
[image]

and the data preview should look like -

| query | user | referenced.keyword_db_tb | referenced.dataset | referenced.tablename |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| select a.*, b.* from dsip.accounts a join qwe.sales b | sys | 123 | dsip | accounts |
|  |  |  | qwe | sales |
| select * from forkp.facts where id in (select id from hjp.classes) | sys | 456 | forkp | facts |
|  |  |  | hjp | classes |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below approach

```
select query, user, array( 
    select as struct keyword_db_tb, dataset, tablename
    from t.keyword_db_tb keyword_db_tb with offset
    full outer join (select * from t.dataset dataset with offset) using (offset)
    full outer join (select * from t.tablename tablename with offset) using (offset)
  ) as reference
from your_table t
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]